# Transferring Python projects to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a python project where the main .py file imports other .py files and the main file is then run for different input arguments using a .sh file. Can anyone guide me how to transfer and run the entire project on Google Colab?

Answer (score 10):

Commit your files to a git repo.
In a new google colab file, run

```
!git clone <http url of your repo>
```

Then execute your program

```
!python main.py --foo bar
```

Alternatively, you could upload your project to google drive and then import the project from there.

Comment: This requires my Git repo to be public, right? Or could I give limited access just to colab somehow?